# Rust iterator or slice sliding mutable window

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I tried to do a "proper" Rust version of bubble sort using iterators.
The obvious code contains the lines:

```
let mut vi = v.windows(2);
for mut i in vi {
    if i[0] > i[1] {
        i.swap(0, 1);
    }
}
```

But I get the error

```
`i` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

Is there a way to get a mutable reference to the pairs of elements of a vector from an iterator?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows), there is no `slice::windows_mut`, which is what you'd look for to access the values mutably. However, it goes on to suggest `Cell::as_slice_of_cells` as a solution to your exact problem:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

let vi = Cell::as_slice_of_cells(Cell::from_mut(&mut v)).windows(2);
for i in vi {
    if i[0] > i[1] {
        i[0].swap(&i[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to GAT, it is actually possible to build your own `WindowsMut` now. I wouldn't be surprised if it makes it into the stdlib soonish.

```rust
#![feature(slice_first_last_chunk)]

trait LendingIterator {
    type Item<'a>
    where
        Self: 'a;

    fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'a>>;
}

pub struct WindowsMut<'x, const N: usize, T> {
    slice: &'x mut [T],
    index: usize,
}

impl<'x, const N: usize, T> WindowsMut<'x, N, T> {
    fn new(slice: &'x mut [T]) -> Self {
        Self { slice, index: 0 }
    }
}

impl<'x, const N: usize, T> LendingIterator for WindowsMut<'x, N, T> {
    type Item<'a> = &'a mut [T; N] where Self: 'a;

    fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'a>> {
        let Self { slice, index } = self;
        let ans = slice[*index..].first_chunk_mut();
        *index += 1;
        ans
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
    loop {
        let mut changed = false;
        let mut vi = WindowsMut::new(&mut v);
        while let Some([x, y]) = vi.next() {
            if *x > *y {
                std::mem::swap(x, y);
                changed = true
            }
        }
        if !changed {
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("{v:?}");
    // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the nice core library provides helpful comments when hovering over `windows()`,  so I could find a solution:

```
let mut v = vec![5, 2, 3, 7, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3];
let mut vi = &mut v[..];
let slice_of_cells: &[Cell<i32>] = Cell::from_mut(vi).as_slice_of_cells();
let mut sorted = false;
while !sorted {
    sorted = true;
    for w in slice_of_cells.windows(2) {
        if w[0] > w[1] {
            Cell::swap(&w[0], &w[1]);
            sorted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

or the "very ideomatic" way without an explicit loop on the iter:

```
let mut v = vec![5, 2, 3, 7, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3];
let slice_of_cells: &[Cell<i32>] = Cell::from_mut(&mut v[..]).as_slice_of_cells();
let mut sorted = false;
while !sorted {
    sorted = true;
    slice_of_cells.windows(2).for_each(|w| {
        if w[0] > w[1] {
            Cell::swap(&w[0], &w[1]);
            sorted = false;
        }
    });
}
```

:)

Comment: [`for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) is **less** idiomatic than a `for` loop, even it's documentation tells you so.